# Adding OR clause in Node selection criteria - HTMLAgility

Tags: asp.net, html-agility-pack, selectnodes

Can I put OR clause in node selection using HTMLAgility

```
(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection)doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class=\"roomPrice figure\"]");
```

What I need is some times it should be like `SelectNodes("//td[@class=\"roomPrice figure\"]");`
 and some times it is like `SelectNodes("//td[@class=\"roomPrice figure bb\"]");`

I need to get both either class will `roomPrice figure` OR `roomPrice figure bb`

How can I accomplish this.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xpath does have an OR operator. Try this for your selection query -

```
"//td[@class=\"roomPrice figure\" or @class=\"roomPrice figure bb\"]"
```